# Structure for MVC4 Survey Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel, survey

I am trying to figure out the model structure for a survey app, using the MVC architecture.  Actually it is a Q&A section within a larger WebApp.  I have about 120 questions and they will all have set options for answers, no written answers.  Currently I have 3 tables:

```
Question(id, QuestionText)
Answer(id, Userid, Questionid, AnswerOptionId)
AnswerOption(id, Option) - example: Yes, No, 1-10, etc
```

I am trying to figure out how to build my viewmodel and view.  I can't just have something like:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.QuestionText)
```

because there are 120 of them.  Do I need to use a loop or something?  I also don't want to hard code the questions into the app, because I will likely add/remove/edit questions in the future when the app is live.

I did a search but only found apps for creating surveys, not an actual survey built in MVC.  Let me know if you know of any examples.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ran in to this same problem earlier this week. What I ended up doing, successfully, was this:

My Model consists of a list of Questions, which is a custom class I wrote with the necessary properties needed for my scenario:

```
List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
```

My View uses a DropDownList inside of a foreach block as opposed to a DropDownListFor, and I am setting the name using the Id of each question:

```
@foreach (Question question in Model.Questions)
{
     <li>@question.QuestionText</li>
     <li>Answer: @Html.DropDownList(String.Format("ddlAnswer{0}", question.QuestionId), Model.Answers)</li>
}
```

On HttpPost on the Controller, I am passing in the FormCollection as a parameter to the Action and am again iterating through the results set. This would appear to be inefficient but tested in multiple scenarios it runs very quickly.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SurveyModel model, FormCollection form)
{
     foreach (Question question in model.Questions)
     {
          question.QuestionAnswer = form[String.Format("ddlAnswer{0}", question.QuestionId)];
     }
}
```

Comment: Well heck, its worth a shot.  I have had this project on my desk for about 4 months now, so I am open to anything.  Thanks.

Comment: If answers are different for each question, then each question will have a list of answer object. I am trying this, but getting some problem with mapping view model to post action. Answer list is coming with 0 answers in post action